# Reload tableView section with beginUpdates

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am reloading from a UIButton with observers an UITableView on my Swift App.
I'm using this code:

```
self.myTableView.beginUpdates()
self.myTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
self.myTableView.endUpdates()
self.myTableView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

It's working perfectly on iOS 13, but on iOS 12 I need push the UIButton two times to reload correctly an UITableViewCell that contains a multiline UILabel and the headerView.

How can I do or what need I change on my code?

My content of Cell is:

```
let sectionView: UIView = SectionView.fromNib()//Nib haven't nothing added. All from this code
            
 var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
            
 let titleLabel = UILabel()
 titleLabel.text = "Hello World"
 titleLabel.sizeToFit()
 titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

 sectionView.addSubview(titleLabel)
                
 constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: sectionView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10.0))
  constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: sectionView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -10.0))
  constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: sectionView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10.0))
  constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleLabel, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: sectionView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -10.0))
  sectionView.addConstraints(constraints)
```

EDIT: I have also tried performBatchUpdates then rs7 comment but I'm getting the same problem, the row with an UILabel not reload without scroll on iOS 12...

```
self.myTableView.performBatchUpdates ({
            self.myTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
            },
            completion: { (success) in
                self.myTableView.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        )
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `func performBatchUpdates(_ updates: (() -> Void)?, 
              completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)` instead?

Comment: I have edit the question then try this and this not working, but thanks for your reply @rs7

Comment: More likely the problem is in the UIButton action. Try adding some debug logging to see when batch update code is getting called

Comment: On iOS 13 is working perfectly. Code is called with the same logs, but on iOS 12 not reload the visible cell at first time @Dale

Comment: "to reload correctly an UITableViewCell that contains a multiline UILabel." There is no multiline label being populated in a cell in the code that you have shown us.

Comment: Post the contents of your cellForRowAt method

Comment: I have added the content of cell. Thanks for your reply. @RobertCrabtree